Iterate Nested Object based on each Index


const networkChart = NodeClassification;
  const itemKey = Object.values(networkChart).map((x) => Object.keys(x)[0])
  const itemKey1 = Object.values(networkChart).map((x) => Object.values(x)[0])

  itemKey1.map((item, index) => {
    return (
    item.group = itemKey[index],
    item.Vendor = Object.keys(networkChart)[index]
    )
  })

  // itemKey1.map((item, index) => {
  //   item.group = itemKey[index].toUpperCase()
  // })

  const netArr = itemKey1?.map((data, index) => {
    return {
      "group": data.group,
      "key": data.Vendor,
      "value": data.DownCount
    }
  })



Below "NodeClassification" having nested object in each object having there item objects which I need to break this to form array of object. Result of array of object as shown below to from a structure with new key & existing values.
Below attached the bar need to form in this structure on array of object.
JSON Object Structure:
    "NodeClassification": {
             "Mobile": {
                "NORMAL": {
                   "DownCount": 2
                },
                "VIP": {
                   "DownCount": 2
                }
             },
             "MobileRAN": {
                "NORMAL": {
                   "DownCount": 4
                },
                 "VIP": {
                       "DownCount": 4
                    },
                "CRITICAL": {
                       "DownCount": 4
                    }
             }
          }
        
    Result I need based on Array Of Object Structure:
    [{
        group: 'NORMAL',
        key: 'Mobile',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        group: 'VIP',
        key: 'Mobile',
        value: 2
      },
      {
        group: 'NORMAL',
        key: 'MobileRAN',
        value: 4
      },
      {
        group: 'VIP',
        key: 'MobileRAN',
        value: 4
      },
      {
        group: 'CRITICAL',
        key: 'MobileRAN',
        value: 4
      }
    ] 



what goes wrong? please add your code.

I have added code now, In that I'm accessing only 0th index object not able loop each index in object

You could get the entries and map the nested entries.


const
    data = { NodeClassification: { Mobile: { NORMAL: { DownCount: 2 }, VIP: { DownCount: 2 } }, MobileRAN: { NORMAL: { DownCount: 4 }, VIP: { DownCount: 4 }, CRITICAL: { DownCount: 4 } } } },
    result = Object
        .entries(data.NodeClassification)
        .flatMap(([key, o]) => Object
            .entries(o)
            .map(([group, { DownCount: value }]) => ({ group, key, value }))
        );

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




A combination of Object#entries and Array#reduce could help:


const input={NodeClassification:{Mobile:{NORMAL:{DownCount:2},VIP:{DownCount:2}},MobileRAN:{NORMAL:{DownCount:4},VIP:{DownCount:4},CRITICAL:{DownCount:4}}}};

const result = Object.entries(input.NodeClassification)
  .reduce((r, [group, obj]) => (
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, {DownCount: value}]) => r.push({group, key, value})
  ), r), []);
  
console.log(result);



Smaller but a bit less performant:


const input={NodeClassification:{Mobile:{NORMAL:{DownCount:2},VIP:{DownCount:2}},MobileRAN:{NORMAL:{DownCount:4},VIP:{DownCount:4},CRITICAL:{DownCount:4}}}};

const result = Object.entries(input.NodeClassification)
  .reduce((r, [group, obj]) => r.concat(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, {DownCount: value}]) => ({group, key, value}))), []);
  
console.log(result);
  



More smaller but more less performant (due iterators in Array#flatMap:


const input={NodeClassification:{Mobile:{NORMAL:{DownCount:2},VIP:{DownCount:2}},MobileRAN:{NORMAL:{DownCount:4},VIP:{DownCount:4},CRITICAL:{DownCount:4}}}};

const result = Object.entries(input.NodeClassification)
  .flatMap(([group, obj]) => Object.entries(obj).map(([key, {DownCount: value}]) => ({group, key, value})));
  
console.log(result);




Thanks Alexander Nenashev Its worked.
